# reCAPTCHA is accepting random values

Tags: laravel-4, recaptcha

I'm using Greg Gilbert's reCAPTCHA validator for Laravel 4 (https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha).

I know that reCAPTCHA only needs one word on two to validate forms but my problem is different. I actually have a single word displayed on my reCAPTCHA, the second one is missing. And unfortunately, the displayed word is the "pictured-word", you know, the word for which you can write whatever you like and it will be accepted.

[image: reCAPTCHA bug]

So if it shows number 109, I can write "108" and my form will be accepted.

How to fix that please ?

Comment: I think reCAPTCHA has some *error tolerance* implemented. Have you tried entering "cat" or "666" instead?

Comment: You're right, text or "strange" numbers are not accepted. But this isn't what I expected when I decided to use reCAPTCHA. I mean, there's usually two words to write and there's only one here. And even when it's not the exact one, it's still accepted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I've found that if I use Firefox's "Private navigation" window, my reCAPTCHA is displaying 2 words instead of 1 as I described here.

It means that if you are connected to your Google account on your web browser, reCAPTCHA "trusts" you a little bit more than a not-connected user and shows you only one word/number.